# Angular Universal nginx Rocky Linux configuration

Tags: angular, nginx

I am trying to install an Angular Universal app on the Rocky Linux 9 with the nginx version 1.20.1 . This is a default Angular Universal app with no added code.

When I started the app  the Firefox browser displayed Internal Server Error and in the console the following error: " Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at http://localhost:4000/favicon.ico (“default-src”).

The same app with the same settings is working perfectly on the Rocky Linux 8 with the nginx version 1.14.1 .